# Scroll category at the window center on click

Tags: jquery, html

I am using adminlte admin template as my practice project with php and jquery.

**What I want:**

I need that if I click on a sidebar category it scroll's to the center of the window area / document area which is visible to the users window.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for **anchors**.

1) Create the link like this:

```
<a href="#anchor">Link Text</a>
```

2) And add the element that you want to scroll to:

```
<div id="anchor">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
```

Or you can use the jQuery for a scroll to a particular element:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementToScroll").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```